# Parameters in a caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, parameters

I have a simple figure with a code like this:

```
 \begin {figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  % 
  \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1]
  \def \r {1/4} % y-scaling
  %
  % PARAMET.
  \def \a {1}   %x^6
  \def \b {-6}  %x^5
  \def \c {7}   %x^4
  \def \d {12}  %x^3
  \def \e {-17} %x^2
  \def \f {0}   %x^1
  \def \g {0}   % x^0
  %axis
  \draw[->,very thick](-4,0) -- (5,0) node [right] {x};
  \draw[->,very thick] (0,-3) -- (0,4) node [above] {y};
    %graph 
     \draw [variable=\t, color=blue, thick,domain= -1.5:3.2,samples=80] 
      plot (\t,    { \r*( \a*((\t)^6)+\b*((\t)^5)+\c*((\t)^4)+\d*((\t)^3)    +\e*((\t)^2)+\f*((\t))+\g) } );
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\caption 
{$y=x^6-6x^5+7x^4+12x^3-17x^2$}
\end{figure}
```

I want to change the parameters so that I can represents different polynomials. Is it possible to parametrize the caption in such a way that when I change the parameters and the caption change without having to rewrite it?

Comment: Put your `\def`initions outside the `tikzpicture` environment and inside the `figure` environment and use them in the argument of `\caption`. This is because the `tikzpicture` environment (in fact, _every_ environment) is a group, so that `\def`initions inside such environment are _local_ to that environment. In your code, `\a`, `\b` etc are undefined outside the `tikzpicture` environment. The suggested edit makes the whole `figure` as the scope of your macros and so the caption, too.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work !. There is  a way to avoid to have the terms $0 x^i$ if a parameter is null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move your `\def`s outside the `tikzpicture` (otherwise, they don't survive the group created for the environment).

The caption is provided using

```
\caption{$y=\protect\polynomial{\g,\f,\e,\d,\c,\b,\a}$}
```

where `\polynomial` from the [`polynomial`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polynomial) package gives the desired formatting for the polynomials. In fact, the code uses a redefinition of `\polynomial` suggested by **egreg** in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257024/3954) to [How to delay expansion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257020/3954):

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \gonzalo_poly:n \polynomial
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gonzalo_poly:n { x }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\polynomial}{m}
 {
  \gonzalo_poly:x { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{polynomial}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \gonzalo_poly:n \polynomial
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gonzalo_poly:n { x }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\polynomial}{m}
 {
  \gonzalo_poly:x { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\def \r {1/4} % y-scaling
% PARAMET.
\def \a {1}   %x^6
\def \b {-6}  %x^5
\def \c {7}   %x^4
\def \d {12}  %x^3
\def \e {-17} %x^2
\def \f {0}   %x^1
\def \g {0}   %x^0
  \centering
  % 
  \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1]
  %axis
  \draw[->,very thick](-4,0) -- (5,0) node [right] {x};
  \draw[->,very thick] (0,-3) -- (0,4) node [above] {y};
    %graph 
     \draw [variable=\t, color=blue, thick,domain= -1.5:3.2,samples=80] 
      plot (\t,    { \r*( \a*((\t)^6)+\b*((\t)^5)+\c*((\t)^4)+\d*((\t)^3)    +\e*((\t)^2)+\f*((\t))+\g) } );
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\caption{$y=\polynomial{\g,\f,\e,\d,\c,\b,\a}$}
\end{figure}

\begin {figure}[!hb]
\def \r {1} % y-scaling
% PARAMET.
\def \a {0}  %x^6
\def \b {0}  %x^5
\def \c {-2} %x^4
\def \d {0}  %x^3
\def \e {3}  %x^2
\def \f {0}  %x^1
\def \g {3}  %x^0
  \centering
  % 
  \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1]
  %axis
  \draw[->,very thick](-4,0) -- (5,0) node [right] {x};
  \draw[->,very thick] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node [above] {y};
    %graph 
     \draw [variable=\t, color=blue, thick,domain= -1.5:1.5,samples=80] 
      plot (\t,    { \r*( \a*((\t)^6)+\b*((\t)^5)+\c*((\t)^4)+\d*((\t)^3)    +\e*((\t)^2)+\f*((\t))+\g) } );
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$y=\polynomial{\g,\f,\e,\d,\c,\b,\a}$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: great. I did not know this package. There's a way to avoid the $+-$ sign?

Comment: @EmilioNovati I'm working on it. My attempts failed, so I opened [a question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257020/3954) about this.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Please see the updated answer.