# How to delay expansion

Tags: expansion

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynomial}

\begin{document}
\def\a{-3}
\def\b{-2}
\def\c{-4}
\[
\polynomial{\a,\b,\c}\quad\polynomial{-3,-2,-4}
\]
\end{document}
```

As can be seen in the result

[image]

the first `\polynomial` produces extra `+` signs in front of negative coefficients, most probably due to late expansion of `\a`, `\b`, and `\c`. How can this be prevented?

### Edit:

The solution provided

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\polynomial{\a,\b,\c}}\x
```

fails in a moving argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynomial}

\begin{document}
\def\a{-3}
\def\b{-2}
\def\c{-4}
\begin{figure}
\caption{$\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\polynomial{\a,\b,\c}}\x$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What modifications are required in this case?

This question appeared while providing an answer to [Parameters in a caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257010/3954).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can redefine `\polynomial` to expand its argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynomial,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \gonzalo_poly:n \polynomial
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gonzalo_poly:n { x }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\polynomial}{m}
 {
  \gonzalo_poly:x { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\def\a{-3}
\def\b{-2}
\def\c{-4}

X
\caption{$\polynomial{\a,\b,\c}$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I like this. It's perfectly in line with my intention to learn `expl3` syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to *force* expansion of the arguments before `\polynomial`. A typical approach would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynomial}

\begin{document}
\def\a{-3}
\def\b{-2}
\def\c{-4}
\[
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\polynomial{\a,\b,\c}}\x
\quad\polynomial{-3,-2,-4}
\]
\end{document}
```

assuming that `\a`, `\b` and `\c` can be taken to be fully expandable (as here).

Answer (score 7):

You can declare a robust command so it is safe in a caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynomial}
\DeclareRobustCommand\xpolynomial[1]{%
\edef\next{\noexpand\protect\noexpand\polynomial{#1}}\next}


\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
\def \a{-3}
\def\b{-2}
\def \c{-4}

\caption{$\xpolynomial{\a,\b,\c}$}

\end{table}

zzzz

\end{document}
```

Or to do it locally as requested in comments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynomial}



\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
\def \a{-3}
\def\b{-2}
\def \c{-4}
\def\xpolynomial#1#2{%
\edef#1{\noexpand\protect\noexpand\polynomial{#2}}}
\xpolynomial\thispoly{\a,\b,\c}

\caption{$\thispoly$}

\end{table}

zzzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, David. Let's say I don't want to declare it robust from the beginning. Would it be possible to `\protect` what needs to be protected in `\edef\next{\noexpand\protect\noexpand\polynomial{#1}}\next}` so it works in captions?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina updated answer